# check role of user in <sec:authorize>

Tags: spring, spring-security, taglib

How can I write check in `<sec:authorize>` if a user is logged in under a specific role, called `specific-role`?

The following check can determine whether or not a user is logged in under **ANY** role:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<sec:authorize var="loggedIn" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

How do I change to above code to check for authentication as `specific-role` instead of checking for ANY role?

Answer (score 1):

```
        <security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
         Blabla
        </security:authorize>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work, which directly solves the stated problem in the OP.  I cannot vouch for other answers, but no doubt other approaches might work also.

```
<sec:authorize var="loggedIn" access="hasRole('specific-role')"/>
```